# Pass php var to curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to pass a php variable into a php curl script, but I am struggling.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
$thestring = "foobar";

$data = '{"last":"$thestring"}'; //this will not work
$data = '{"last":$thestring}'; //this will not work

$data = '{"last":"foobar"}'; //this does work

$url = "https://myjson.com.json"; //not my real url
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = '{"last":"'.$thestring.'"}';
```

You have to concatenate the `$data` string correct. Single quotes `'` are not parsed by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Tino's answer solves your problem by pointing out php variables inside single quotes are not interpreted.

You can also use `json_encode()` instead of having to build the object yourself.

```
$thestring = "foobar";

$data = json_encode (array (
    "last" => $thestring
));
```

Or

```
$thestring = "foobar";

$data = array();
$data["last"] = $thestring;

$data = json_encode($data);
```

You get the idea.